# Paramterized Queries

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, ado.net

I am new Visual C#, and I am confused on how to write parameterized queries. Here is my code without them,

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Insert_Data
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ZTABASSUM\\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=IntroDataBase;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("Insert into employee values ('"+ textBox1.Text +"' , " + textBox2.Text + ", '" + textBox3.Text + "',  " + textBox4.Text + ", " + textBox5.Text + ");", con);
            int o = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show(o + ":Record has been inserted");
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure on how to write parameterized queries for each of the text boxes.

Comment: There are ton's of examples and tutorials showing how to do this. here's one of them. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx. And if you really want help, you should show us what's you've tried.

Comment: If you're new to C#, you owe it to yourself to check out the `Entity Framework`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added notes in the code along with a `best practices` recap after.

```
// best practice - use meaningful method names
private void buttonSaveEmployee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // best practice - wrap all database connections in a using block so they are always closed & disposed even in the event of an Exception
    // best practice - retrieve the connection string by name from the app.config or web.config (depending on the application type) (note, this requires an assembly reference to System.configuration)
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionName"].ConnectionString))
    {
        // best practice - use column names in your INSERT statement so you are not dependent on the sql schema column order
        // best practice - always use parameters to avoid sql injection attacks and errors if malformed text is used like including a single quote which is the sql equivalent of escaping or starting a string (varchar/nvarchar)
        // best practice - give your parameters meaningful names just like you do variables in your code
        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO employee (FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth /*etc*/) VALUES (@firstName, @lastName, @dateOfBirth /*etc*/)", con);

        // best practice - always specify the database data type of the column you are using
        // best practice - check for valid values in your code and/or use a database constraint, if inserting NULL then use System.DbNull.Value
        sc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200){Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxFirstName.Text) ? (object) System.DBNull.Value : (object) textBoxFirstName.Text});
        sc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200){Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxLastName.Text) ? (object) System.DBNull.Value : (object) textBoxLastName.Text});

        // best practice - always use the correct types when specifying your parameters, in this case a string is converted to a DateTime type before being assigned to the SqlParameter.Value
        // note - this is not a very robust way to parse a date as the user is never notified in the event of failure, the purpose here is simply to show how to use parameters of various types
        DateTime dob;
        sc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dateOfBirth", SqlDbType.Date){Value = DateTime.TryParse(textBoxDateOfBirth.Text, out dob) ? (object) dob : (object) System.DBNull.Value});

        // best practice - open your connection as late as possible unless you need to verify that the database connection is valid and wont fail and the proceeding code execution takes a long time (not the case here)
        con.Open();
        int o = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show(o + ":Record has been inserted");

        // the end of the using block will close and dispose the SqlConnection
        // best practice - end the using block as soon as possible to release the database connection
    }
}
```

---

### Best practice recap for working with [ADO.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021(v=vs.110).aspx)

- Wrap all database connections in a using block so they are always closed & disposed even in the event of an Exception. See [using Statement (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) for more information on using statements
- Retrieve the connection strings by name from the app.config or web.config (depending on the application type)

  - This requires an assembly reference to `System.configuration`
  - See [Connection Strings and Configuration Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx) for additional information on how to structure your configuration file
- Always use parameters for incoming values to

  - Avoid [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks
  - Avoid errors if malformed text is used like including a single quote which is the sql equivalent of escaping or starting a string (varchar/nvarchar)
  - Letting the database provider reuse query plans (not supported by all database providers) which increases efficiency
- When working with parameters

  - Give your Sql parameters meaningful names just like you do variables in your code
  - Specify the database data type of the column you are using, this ensures the wrong parameter types is not used which could lead to unexpected results
  - Validate your incoming parameters before you pass them into the command, there is an expression called garbage in garbage out. Validate incoming values as early as possible in the stack
  - Use the correct types when assigning your parameter values, example: do not assign the string value of a DateTime, instead assign an actual DateTime instance to the value of the parameter
  - Do not use the method [AddWithValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), the main reason is it is very easy to forget to specify the parameter type or the precision/scale when needed. For additional information see [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)
- When using database connections

  - Open the connection as late as possible and close it as soon as possible. This is a general guideline when working with any external resource
  - Never share database connections (example: having a singleton host a shared database connection). Have your code always create a new database connection instance when needed and then have the calling code dispose of it and "throw it away" when it is done. The reason for this is

    1. Most database providers have some sort of connection pooling so this is very cheap to do in managed code
    2. It eliminates any future errors if the code starts working with multiple threads

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @ZohraTabassum - no problem. If this answers your question please mark it as such using the grey checkbox on the side of the answer, if you feel another answer was better and helped you more then mark that one.

Comment: This is a really nice high quality answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the create parameter method on SQL command object

Change your string in the SQL command to

`"Insert into employee values (@Employee1,@Employee2,@Employee3,@Employee4,@Employee5);"`

Then before executing the query add the parameters :

```
sc.Parameters.AddRange(new[]{

    new SqlParameter("@Employee1",SqlDbType.VarChar,255){ Value= textBox1.Text},
    new SqlParameter("@Employee2",SqlDbType.VarChar,255){ Value= textBox2.Text},
    new SqlParameter("@Employee3",SqlDbType.VarChar,255){ Value= textBox3.Text},
    new SqlParameter("@Employee4",SqlDbType.VarChar,255){ Value= textBox4.Text},
    new SqlParameter("@Employee5",SqlDbType.VarChar,255){ Value= textBox5.Text}

});
```

**Note :** This is assuming that the type of your SQL variables will be a `VARCHAR` and the size will be `255`, for more information about the method being used and the `SqlParameter` constructor being used check out MSDN for more documentation.

- [SqlParameterCollection.AddRange Method (SqlParameter[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e42546a(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [SqlParameter Constructor (String, SqlDbType, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hex23w80(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Please add the `SqlDbType` in your example when using `AddWithValue`. See [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @Igor I agree. AddWithValue is not only inferring types (bad) but it is also not _clean code_ in my opinion.

`command.Parameters.Add("inId", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = primaryId;`
`command.Parameters.Add("refCursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;`


Please also note that you should add parameters in the order they appear in the SQL, Package Call, Stored Procedure, or Function.

Comment: @AndrewGrinder -- we are so not using Oracle here, why have the Oracle types?

Comment: @Hogan Same principle applies to SQL in the format. You can use SqlTypes. Common sense.

Comment: @Igor updated to add `SqlParameter` with type and size specified

Answer (score 1):

parameterized queries is used for avoid sql injection . The query which contain not parameters ( data) directly is called parameterized query. by using this we can avoid sql injection (one type of hacking).

Example for parameterized query in c#

```
    string strQuery;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    strQuery = "insert into customers (CustomerID, CompanyName) values(@CustomerID, @CompanyName)";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", "A234");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", "DCB");
String strConnString = system.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
```

..

Similarly you can use for select query also ..

for reference see this [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Parameterized-queries-to-prevent-SQL-Injection-Attacks-in-SQL-Server.aspx)

Comment: Please add the `SqlDbType` in your example when using `AddWithValue`. See [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a database context you can do it like this:

```
int rowsAffected = context.
  ExecuteStoreCommand("Insert into employee values ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4})",
                       textBox1.Text, 
                       textBox2.Text,
                       textBox3.Text, 
                       textBox4.Text,
                       textBox5.Text);
MessageBox.Show(rowsAffected + ":Record has been inserted");\
```

cf https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358769%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please stop using AddWithValue as it infers database type (bad) and is also not *clean code* in my opinion.

Here's some simple code to get you started.

```
OracleConnection connection = GetConnection();
OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = procedure;
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.Add("INID", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = person.PersonID;
command.Parameters.Add("REFCURSOR", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Don't mind it being Oracle, the same principle applies to SQL.