# How to update a table in database using c#?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table named "Members" in my database.

In a form, I have some `Labels`, `TextBoxes`, a `DataGridView` and a few Buttons.

When I click a row in the `DataGridView`, the whole data appears in the corresponding `TextBox` correctly.

I have added an "Update" button - which, when clicked I want the database table information to update instantly.

I have written the following code on "Update" button click event. But it shows me error continuously. Please help. I badly need the solution.

```
string Query = "UPDATE Members SET MemberID='" + MemberIDTextBox.Text + "'|| Name='" + NameTextBox.Text + "'|| Gender='" + GenderComboBox.Text + "'|| Address='" + AddressTextBox.Text + "'|| NID='" + NationalIDTextBox.Text + "'|| DOB='" + DOBTimePicker.Text + "'|| BloodGroup='" + BloodGroupTextBox.Text + "'|| Height='" + HeightTextBox.Text + "'|| Weight='" + WeightTextBox.Text + "'|| ChestSize='" + ChestSizeTextBox.Text + "'|| MusclesSize='" + MusclesSizeTextBox.Text + "'|| AbsPack='" + AbsPackTextBox.Text + "'|| Profession='" + ProfessionTextBox.Text + "'|| Contact='" + ContactTextBox.Text + "' WHERE MemberID='" + MemberIDTextBox.Text + "'";


SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Query, Connection);
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: I believe you want to use a data adapter as the binding source of your grid.  Then in your update button you have a command like DataAdapter.SaveChanges().  I have not done this in a while but I remember there were plenty of examples on the net.

Comment: What are the `||` symbols supposed to be?

Comment: I think it will do as "OR".

Comment: See this previous SO answer [Paramterized Queries](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38575547/1260204) which has an example of an INSERT statement which you could convert to an UPDATE statement. It shows how to utilize a parameterized query with best practice hints.

Comment: I don't know exactly how to make it work as I want.
I just want; after I change any of the TextBoxes value and click on Update button, instantly the table "Members" would updated. How should I write the code in Update button click event??

Comment: SQL Injection Alert! Arggghhhh! http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0926bc/sql-injection/

Comment: You just have the update query all wrong. See codenoir's answer and my comment.

Comment: @Crowcoder,
yes sir. my code is all wrong but I want the right one. please help.

Answer (score 2):

Using a parameterized query:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Members set Name=@Name, Gender=@Gender, Address=@Address, NID=@NID, DOB=@DOB, BloodGroup=@BloodGroup, Height=@Height, Weight=@Weight, ChestSize=@ChestSize, MusclesSizes=@MusclesSizes, AbsPack=@AbsPack, Profession=@Profession, Contact=@Contact" + " where MemberID=@MemberID", Connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberID", MemberIDTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", NameTextBox.Text);
// ...
//Keep adding parameters
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Its not working still. It says that "SqlException was unhandled"

Comment: If MemberID is your primary key, you can't update it. I've edited the code

Comment: And btw, start trying with a few parameters until you have fixed the error:
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Members set Name=@Name" + " where MemberID=@MemberID", Connection);

Comment: Yes.. I did exactly like this but still its not working and says that "SqlException was unhandled"

Comment: did you convert your MemberID to int? are you using the correct types?

Comment: oh , I forgot to ask, but how's your connection string? is it correct?

Comment: Yes. MemberID type I used is int. As I said, I've already added some data into database using insert command and I retrieve the data from DataGridView in their individual TextBoxes when I click in a row of DataGridView. I just want now to change any of the TextBoxes value and Update.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same correct ConnectionString that I used in insert command to insert data in the same form.

Comment: You need to look at the InnerException or Message property of the SqlException.

Answer (score 1):

***Solution:*** **Change the double-pipe (`||`) characters to comma (`,`)**

Like so:

```
string Query = "UPDATE Members SET MemberID='" + MemberIDTextBox.Text + "',  Name='" + NameTextBox.Text + "',  Gender='" + GenderComboBox.Text + "',  Address='" + AddressTextBox.Text + "',  NID='" + NationalIDTextBox.Text + "',  DOB='" + DOBTimePicker.Text + "',  BloodGroup='" + BloodGroupTextBox.Text + "',  Height='" + HeightTextBox.Text + "',  Weight='" + WeightTextBox.Text + "',  ChestSize='" + ChestSizeTextBox.Text + "',  MusclesSize='" + MusclesSizeTextBox.Text + "',  AbsPack='" + AbsPackTextBox.Text + "',  Profession='" + ProfessionTextBox.Text + "',  Contact='" + ContactTextBox.Text + "' WHERE MemberID='" + MemberIDTextBox.Text + "'";
```

But you should **really** consider a parameterized query. You're just *ASKING* for a SQL Injection attack with your current implementation.

---

**How do I use parameterized queries?**

There's already a [well-explained answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35163362/6240567) here, on StackOverflow, that gives good examples of how to use parameterized queries in your code.

---

**What is SQL Injection?**

It is where piece of SQL code is essentially exposed through simple string concatenation - mostly from user input (text fields etc.) *as in your OP.*

If a malicious "query" is input into said field, the potential injector could cause severe issues, and cause a lot of damage, access/edit parts of the database they're not meant to etc.

It is not only a pet hate for most of the world's programmers when other developers expose their code to SQL Injection, it's a real-world problem that can do (and has) destroyed businesses.

SQL Injection attacks are virtually "blind", however they can be *very* desctructive.

---

**Some useful resources**

- [C-Sharp Corner's article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0926bc/sql-injection/) gives you a more in-depth description as
  to what SQL Injection is and how to prevent it
- Watch [Computerphile's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ciNHn38EyRc) on how (scarily) easy it is to run an SQL
  Injection attack on code exposed to it

Comment: ... and if `MemberID` (or anything else) is numeric, don't put single quote around the value. And if it is an identity field you cannot update it.

Comment: Which is another reason to use parameterized queries - you don't have to deal with what needs to be quoted or not.

Comment: Yes sir, I've replaced all double-pipe with comma. But still it gives me error. Its not working. :-(

Comment: It would have helped quite a bit if you posted the error message you're getting.

Comment: @pinGOL, you have to provide the error when you say you have an error. I assume it it because `MemberID` is a primary key and you cannot update it. Remove `MemberID` from the query. I suggest you update your question to show what you have now tried and what error you are getting.

Comment: But also ... Forlani has posted a parameterized version of your SQL call.  I'd try it.

Comment: @Crowcoder, it says that "SqlException was unhandled"
I think the query is still not correct at all.

Comment: Looking at your so-called "query", my guess is that your "`MemberID`" column uses an integer-based column (`smallint` at a guess)? As @Crowcoder mentioned - numeric values don't require `'` around them, and you can't update identity fields. As per various comments and in this answer, using **Parameterized Queries** will undoubtedly solve all of life's problems for you :)

Comment: I've updated the code like @Forlani mentioned. But still its not working..